# Minimum weighted solution norm

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, normed-spaces, projection

I'm trying to solve the following problem with the orthogonality principle:

$$
\pmb x^*= \text{argmin}\;\; \pmb x^H Q \pmb x \quad s.t. \quad A\pmb x = \pmb b   
$$

I think I'll get something that looks like $QA^H(AQA^H)^{-1}$ but I keep getting stuck because the constraint isn't written in terms of the inner product defined by $\langle \pmb x, \pmb y\rangle = \pmb y^H Q \pmb x$

Comment: $Ax-b=\text{what?}$

Comment: @obareey, fixed, sorry

Comment: Please show us the work that you've done so far.

Comment: One approach is to use a change of variables. If we take $M = Q^{1/2}$ and $\mathbf y = M\mathbf x$, then we can rewrite the minimization problem as 
$$
\mathbf y^* = \arg \min \mathbf y^H \mathbf y \quad \text{s.t.} \quad (AM^{-1/2}) \mathbf y = \mathbf b.
$$

Comment: @f Also, it is possible to rewrite the constraint as
$$
\langle A \mathbf x - \mathbf  b,A \mathbf x - \mathbf  b\rangle = 0 
$$
if that helps.

Comment: I agree with you @BenGrossmann. I think the answer key is wrong because the notions of orthogonal are different.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/19mpyHBrfcrmzMWIUlHJLs8Op0UtjpkIP4goQhW82IHs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @f The answer key seems to do exactly what my first comment recommends; I don't see where the "orthogonality principle" comes into play

Comment: Ahh okay, let me look at it longer. In the problem from the book they refer to the projection theorem as the orthogonality principle, but maybe that's not normal (no pun intended)